# Reading in and splitting file based on number of data elements in rows

Tags: r, file

I have a file with data that repeats a header that has 5 columns while the data itself has 4 columns. How can I have R read this file in and split the file into data frames or a list when this header comes up?

I could try to read it, make it loop though each line, and have it find where there is 5 columns and break it there but I have hundreds of files and I am trying to find something that might be a quicker solution.

```
  0.02513611 360.00  75.00 0.40 -1.64
  0 0.3644 0.457946 -3.052621E-5
  1 -1.1644 0.627169 -2.102580E-5
  2 -0.6293 0.951162 -2.760053E-6
.........
  198 32.8518 1.000293  2.854190E-7
  199 29.1062 0.999455 -5.351427E-7
  0.02609167  30.01  75.00 0.40 -1.64
  0 0.2115 1.012327  6.942146E-7 
  1 -0.5529 1.048153  2.715609E-6
  2 -34.9513 1.021430  1.211076E-6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose an option would be to read this in with `read.table` with `fill=TRUE`, which will fill with `NA` values when different rows have different number of data elements. Then you could use `split` to break this up into a list of data frames, where the first row is the header and the subsequent rows are the data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="0.02513611 360.00 75.00 0.40 -1.64
0 0.3644 0.457946 -3.052621E-5
1 -1.1644 0.627169 -2.102580E-5
2 -0.6293 0.951162 -2.760053E-6
198 32.8518 1.000293 2.854190E-7
199 29.1062 0.999455 -5.351427E-7
0.02609167 30.01 75.00 0.40 -1.64
0 0.2115 1.012327 6.942146E-7
1 -0.5529 1.048153 2.715609E-6
2 -34.9513 1.021430 1.211076E-6", fill=TRUE)

split(dat, cumsum(!is.na(dat$V5)))
# $`1`
#             V1       V2        V3            V4    V5
# 1   0.02513611 360.0000 75.000000  4.000000e-01 -1.64
# 2   0.00000000   0.3644  0.457946 -3.052621e-05    NA
# 3   1.00000000  -1.1644  0.627169 -2.102580e-05    NA
# 4   2.00000000  -0.6293  0.951162 -2.760053e-06    NA
# 5 198.00000000  32.8518  1.000293  2.854190e-07    NA
# 6 199.00000000  29.1062  0.999455 -5.351427e-07    NA
# 
# $`2`
#            V1       V2        V3           V4    V5
# 7  0.02609167  30.0100 75.000000 4.000000e-01 -1.64
# 8  0.00000000   0.2115  1.012327 6.942146e-07    NA
# 9  1.00000000  -0.5529  1.048153 2.715609e-06    NA
# 10 2.00000000 -34.9513  1.021430 1.211076e-06    NA
```

Likely you'll be using `file=` instead of `text=` when calling `read.table`.